# How to skip step in github action when [no ci] present in the commit comment

Tags: github-actions

As it is stated in the title:

I need to skip tests step (in this case it is the step named "E2E TESTS") in my pipeline but only when "[no ci]" substring is present in the git commit message.

```yaml
name: Pipeline

on: ...

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04 
    timeout-minutes: 10
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18.7.0

      - uses: actions/cache/restore@v3 
        id: restore-cache
        with:
          path: node_modules
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}

      - name: Yarn install
        run: yarn install --production=false

      - uses: actions/cache/save@v3 
        with:
          path: node_modules
          key: ${{ steps.restore-cache.outputs.cache-primary-key }}

      - name: run local server (NODE_ENV=production)
        run: |
          /bin/bash ci_server.sh &

      - name: E2E TESTS
        run: |
          /bin/bash playwright.sh --target docker
```

Edit:

Actually I found the solution.
But first thing is that [no ci] is handled [automatically](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-02-08-github-actions-skip-pull-request-and-push-workflows-with-skip-ci/) and will make skip running entire pipeline so I had to stick to different substring.
I decided to use [quick] string.

and then the final modification look like this:

```
...

      - name: E2E TESTS
        if: "!contains(github.event.head_commit.message, '[quick]')"
        run: |
          /bin/bash playwright.sh --target docker

...
```

Comment: This workflow is missing the `on:` trigger, which determines the event payload from which you'd extract the commit message.

Comment: I skipped it deliberately, to make this code smaller. But thank you.. ;) I'll add something to indicate it's there

Comment: It's crucial, though, because depending on what triggers the workflow, `github.event` looks different.